# Cannot connect to SQL Server - login failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2008, but I'm getting this error:

> *Login failed for user "xyz" because the account is currently locked
>   out.The system administrator can unlock it. (Microsoft SQL Server,
>   Error 18486)*

Please check the image.

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> SQL server has local password policies. If policy is enabled which
>   locks down the account after X number of failed attempts then the
>   account is automatically locked down.This error with 'sa' account is
>   very common. sa is default administartor login available with SQL
>   server. So there are chances that an ousider has tried to bruteforce
>   your system. (This can cause even if a legitimate tries to access the
>   account with wrong password.Sometimes a user would have changed the
>   password without informing others.)

If you know another admin account, you can unlock it using this query,

```
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD='password' UNLOCK
```

**[Read more on this link.](http://weblogs.asp.net/cabhilash/archive/2010/04/07/login-failed-for-user-sa-because-the-account-is-currently-locked-out-the-system-administrator-can-unlock-it.aspx)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But now i didn't do anything . After 20 minutes  i tried to login again and was able to connect Sql server . It's just Surprising how its connected again.????

Comment: ^^^ The story of my life right there.

Comment: It connected cause the lockout automatically is removed after a specified period

Answer (score 4):

There is another way of unlocking. connect to the sql server using windows authentication, but make sure the window user is an admin in sql. then one can go to security folder, select the locked user, go the properties and then to Status. there one need to uncheck the "Login is locked out" and account is unlocked.

Comment: you helped me

Answer (score 3):

From http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/23/sql-server-fix-error-18486-login-failed-for-user-sa-because-the-account-is-currently-locked-out-the-system-administrator-can-unlock-it-unlock-sa-login/

> ALTER LOGIN sa WITH CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
>
> ALTER LOGIN sa WITH CHECK_POLICY = ON; GO

Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have given many failed attempts to DB remotely and sa account was locked.

"ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD='password' UNLOCK" this

Answer (score 0):

If sa is your only Adminstrator account, you can aslo follow the advice given in the [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx) page on MSDN.

[image]